# The user or administrator has not consented to use the application - Send an interactive authorization request for this user and resource

Tags: javascript, c#, azure, asp.net-web-api, dynamics-crm

We're doing [this](http://scaleablesolutions.com/web-api-authentication-from-javascript/) CRM Web API project. The project logs-into Dynamics CRM online instance and gets the list of accounts.

The login seems to be happening fine.
However, the accounts listing is giving the below error:

> AADSTS65001: The user or administrator has not consented to use the application with ID 'xxxx-xxxxx-xxxx-xxx'. Send an interactive authorization request for this user and resource.
>   Trace ID: e3b360d6-39fb-4e61-87d9-26531f30fd7b
>   Correlation ID: 9b2cff0c-074e-44fe-a169-77c8061a7312
>   Timestamp: 2016-10-18 10:12:49Z

The [permissions are properly set](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34885153/2404470):

[image: Azure permissions]

What is the problem?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

An admin must consent to the permissions. You should make an authorization request to Azure AD that includes the parameter `prompt=admin_consent`.

As in the documentation [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-protocols-oauth-code/#request-an-authorization-code), the prompt parameter can have 3 values: login, consent, or admin_consent.

So, you should go to a URL such as https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenant-id/oauth2/authorize?client_id=app-client-id&redirect_uri=encoded-reply-url&response_type=code&prompt=admin_consent.

Replace *tenant-id* with your Azure AD tenant id/domain name, or *common* if your app is multi-tenant. Replace *app-client-id* with your app's client id. Replace *encoded-reply-url* with a URL-encoded reply URL of your app.

An easier way of constructing the URL you need is to go through authentication and just grab the URL in the address bar when you hit Azure AD. Then just add `&prompt=admin_consent` to the URL.

EDIT: With the newest update to the Azure Portal came the ability to grant permissions from the portal directly.

If you go to Azure Active Directory in the new portal, find your app registration there and click *Grant Permissions* under the Required permissions blade.

[image: New Grant Permissions button]

Comment: I was blocked by the same error for days and couldn't figure out why. Thanks for your answer, I know there's bug in the AAD library I used. After fixed it, everything works fine!! Thank you!!

Comment: I got the error "ApplicationName is requesting permissions, which you are not authorized to grant. Contact your administrator, who can grant permissions to this application on your behalf." so I had an AAD administrator click the Grant Permissions button.

Comment: @Trisped You need to have the *Application Admin* role assigned in the O365 Admin Center to the account you login with.

Answer (score 18):

As per Oauth V2.0. you do not need to resend the Scope parameter in the Token API to generate Refresh/access tokens. You don't need to manually specify scopes In the azure portal as well, it will get listed automatically.

It is inherited from your auth_code, you can remove the scope and request, it should work and also once you decode the access_token, you should be able to see the same scopes, you requested during authorization

Comment: Hi @Mihail Duchev
As you suggested, I removed scope while generating access token and refresh token, yes I got only access token, and refresh is missing? may I know the way to get this refresh token? Awaiting your reply

Comment: It worked. I removed the scope and I was able to obtain the access_token and refresh_token. Thanks.

Comment: this worked for me when integratinng msal in angular. Changing scope from ["user.read"] to [ ] fixed the issue

Answer (score 5):

I was getting this error in a native application using ADAL.  I had given all of the correct permissions, but had already received a token from a previous signin.  My issue was that the previous token was stale and did not contain the updated claims.  For me, the solution was to use PromptBehavior.RefreshSession as per the code below.

```
   AuthenticationResult result = await authenticationContext.AcquireTokenAsync(resourceId, clientId, redirectURI, new PlatformParameters(PromptBehavior.RefreshSession, false));
```

As per [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.identitymodel.clients.activedirectory.promptbehavior.aspx), PromptBehavior.RefreshSession "Re-authorizes (through displaying webview) the resource usage, making sure that the resulting access token contains updated claims. If user logon cookies are available, the user will not be asked for credentials again and the logon dialog will dismiss automatically."

Answer (score 4):

For me, this error occurred all of a sudden and that too for few users only.

My setup was, SPA app trying to access API. I deleted the API permission from SPA app registration and added it again. It worked.

Answer (score 3):

The error occurs for the application registered with Azure AD (Delegated Permissions), which requires either user or an administrator’s consent for the permissions it needs.

https://nishantrana.me/2020/12/01/fixed-aadsts65001-the-user-or-administrator-has-not-consented-to-use-the-application-with-id/

Answer (score 0):

Just to put it out there, here's my solution for extracting data from Dynamics Web API using R. You can have Dynamics auto-generate Fetch XML for any data you need in the "Advanced Find" view. This script uses that auto-generated Fetch XML to extract any data you like.

Warning: This Web API is very difficult to work with. It took a lot of research to put this together.

[image]

```
#~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
#~~ Introduction
#~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
# Purpose: Download data from Microsoft Dynamics using a fetch XML request
# Created: 2/23/2021
# Modified: 10/1/2021
# Author: Ryan Bradley 
#
# Resources on this topic:
# https://github.com/r-lib/httr/blob/master/R/oauth-token.r
# https://github.com/r-lib/httr/blob/master/demo/oauth2-azure.r
# https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-register-app
# https://blog.r-hub.io/2021/01/25/oauth-2.0/
# https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/developer/data-platform/authenticate-oauth
# https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customerengagement/on-premises/developer/webapi/discover-url-organization-web-api
# https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/developer/data-platform/webapi/retrieve-and-execute-predefined-queries#use-custom-fetchxml
# https://community.dynamics.com/365/f/dynamics-365-general-forum/378416/resource-not-found-for-the-segment-error-getting-custom-entity-from-common-data-service-web-api
# https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customerengagement/on-premises/developer/introduction-entities#:~:text=The%20entities%20are%20used%20to,Engagement%20(on%2Dpremises).&text=An%20entity%20has%20a%20set,%2C%20Address%20%2C%20and%20OwnerId%20attributes.
# https://datascienceplus.com/accessing-web-data-json-in-r-using-httr/
# https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/developer/data-platform/authenticate-oauth
# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3541711/url-encode-sees-ampersand-as-amp-html-entity
# https://www.inogic.com/blog/2019/04/handling-special-characters-while-executing-fetch-xml-programmatically-in-web-api-rest-call/
# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3541711/url-encode-sees-ampersand-as-amp-html-entity
# https://truenorthit.co.uk/2014/07/dynamics-crm-paging-cookies-some-gotchas/
#~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
#~~ First time set up and maintenance 
#~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
#...........................................................................................
#.. Encode your active directory user name and password with key ring
#...........................................................................................
# This is only relevant if you need to authenticate through a proxy.
#
# You will need to install the keyring package and set your active directory user name
# and password. You can run remove the comments from the 4 lines below and run them to
# install the package and set your AD user name and password.
#
# You will also need to repeat these steps when your active directory information changes.
#
# install.packages("keyring") 
# library(keyring)
# keyring::key_set("id")
# keyring::key_set("pw")
#
#...........................................................................................
#.. Get a token to authenticate with Microsoft Dynamics
#...........................................................................................
#
# 1. Log into the azure portal
#     https://portal.azure.com/#home
# 2. Register a new app
# 3. Generate a client secret on the "Certificates & secrets" page. Save it for later.
# 4. Create an application scope on the "Expose an API" page. 
# 5. Grant the app "user_impersonation" access to "Dynamics CRM (1)"
# 6. Meet with the an Active Directory IT administrator, and have them click
#  "Grand Admin consent for Consumers Energy" on the "API Permissions" page of your app.
#
# If all those steps worked, you should now be able to authenticate using the code below.
#

#~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
#~~ Hard-coded variables
#~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

# Define global setting for importing strings as factors
options(stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
options(httr_oauth_cache=T)

#...........................................................................................
#.. Azure App Data
#...........................................................................................
# Found here:  https://portal.azure.com/#home

# Azure app ID
# Source: "Overview" tab of your application in the Azure portal
client_id <- "YOUR ID" 

# App name
# Source: "Overview" tab of your application in the Azure portal
app_name <- "MY_APP" # not important for authorization grant flow

# Secret ID
# Source: "Clients & Secrets" tab of your application in the Azure portal
client_secret <- "YOUR SECRET"

# Application ID URI.
# Source: "Expose an API" tab of your application in the Azure portal
application_id_uri = "YOUR URI "

#~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
#~~ Load or install packages
#~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
# Load or install librarian
if(require(librarian) == FALSE){
  install.packages("librarian")
  if(require(librarian)== FALSE){stop("Unable to install and load librarian")}
}

# Load multiple packages using the librarian package
librarian::shelf(tidyverse, readxl, RODBC, lubridate, httr, XML, jsonlite, rlist, httpuv, quiet = TRUE)

#~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
#~~  Set up global httr proxy configuration
#~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
# This is only needed if you're connecting through a proxy 

# set_config(use_proxy(url="yourproxy.com",port= 1234
#                      ,username=keyring::key_get("id")
#                      ,password=keyring::key_get("pw")
#                     )
#             )

#~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
#~~ Authenticate with Dynamics
#~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

# Use the default Azure endpoints default ones
azure_endpoint <- oauth_endpoints("azure")

# Create the app instance.
myapp <- oauth_app(
  appname = app_name,
  key = client_id,
  secret = client_secret
)

# Step through the authorization chain:
#    1. You will be redirected to you authorization endpoint via web browser.
#    2. Once you responded to the request, the endpoint will redirect you to
#       the local address specified by httr.
#    3. httr will acquire the authorization code (or error) from the data
#       posted to the redirect URI.
#    4. If a code was acquired, httr will contact your authorized token access
#       endpoint to obtain the token.
mytoken <- oauth2.0_token(azure_endpoint,
                          myapp,
                          scope = application_id_uri,
                          cache = str_cache
)

if (("error" %in% names(mytoken$credentials)) && (nchar(mytoken$credentials$error) > 0)) {
  errorMsg <- paste("Error while acquiring token.",
                    paste("Error message:", mytoken$credentials$error),
                    paste("Error description:", mytoken$credentials$error_description),
                    paste("Error code:", mytoken$credentials$error_codes),
                    sep = "\n"
  )
  stop(errorMsg)
}

#~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
#~~ Begin making requests
#~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

#...........................................................................................
#.. Dynamics API data
#...........................................................................................

# The URL of the Dynamics instace you'd like to connect to
base_url <- "https://YOURPLATFORM.dynamics.com/api/data/v9.2/"

# This part of the URL is added on to the base URL to use the web API 
# to send on a fetchxml request
url_add_on <- "?fetchXml="

# XML retrieved by downloading fetch XML from Microsoft Dyanmics using the "Advanced Find" view. 
# You may need to edit the auto-generated XML, it's not always great. Consider making the alias
# something legible, like I did below.
#
# I copied and pasted the XML into notepad and used find and replace to escape all the quotes.
# " -> \"
#
# Make sure your "order attribute" XML code is unique to every row in the data set. 
# If it's not, if may cause issues when pulling data with more than 5,000 rows.
#
xml <- "<fetch version=\"1.0\" output-format=\"xml-platform\" mapping=\"logical\" distinct=\"false\">
  <entity name=\"amendments\">
    <attribute name=\"seasonyear\" />
    <attribute name=\"enrollmenttype\" />
    <attribute name=\"effectivestartdate\" />
    <attribute name=\"effectiveenddate\" />
    <attribute name=\"contractstartdate\" />
    <attribute name=\"contractenddate\" />
    <attribute name=\"program\" />
    <attribute name=\"programduration\" />
    <attribute name=\"programtype\" />
    <attribute name=\"kwnominations\" />
    <attribute name=\"renewalkw\" />
    <attribute name=\"newkw\" />
    <attribute name=\"account\" />
    <attribute name=\"ownerid\" />
    <attribute name=\"amendmentsid\" />
    <attribute name=\"statuscode\" />
    <attribute name=\"statecode\" />
    <attribute name=\"amendment\" />
    <attribute name=\"name\" />
    <order attribute=\"amendmentsid\" descending=\"false\" />
    <link-entity name=\"salesorder\" from=\"salesorderid\" to=\"order\" visible=\"false\" link-type=\"outer\" alias=\"sales\">
      <attribute name=\"datecontractapproved\" />
    </link-entity>
    <link-entity name=\"account\" from=\"accountid\" to=\"account\" visible=\"false\" link-type=\"outer\" alias=\"account\">
      <attribute name=\"accountmanager\" />
      <attribute name=\"accountnumber\" />
      <attribute name=\"statecode\" />
    </link-entity>
  </entity>
</fetch>"

# Encode the XML into a URL
url_xml <- URLencode(xml)

# Set the dynamics entity/table you wish to use. 
# Entities = Dynamics tables, and attributes = Dynamics columns
# NOTE: MUST BE PLURAL. If your entity is "contact" then put "contacts" and if
# your entity already ends in "s" try adding "es." Example -> amendments -> amendmentses
#
# You should be able to find the entity name in the first or 2nd line of an auto-generated
# XML. Example:   <entity name=\"amendments\">
dynamics_entity <- "amendmentses"

# Create a Web API query URL
url_fetch <- paste0(base_url, dynamics_entity, url_add_on, url_xml)
# url_fetch

# Send GET request. 
resp <- GET(url = url_fetch
            , config(token = mytoken)
            , add_headers(Prefer = "odata.include-annotations=\"*\"") # This header is required to get legible text returned along with a paging cookies (if applicable)
)

#...........................................................................................
#.. Check for a valid API response
#...........................................................................................
if(http_error(resp) == TRUE){
  print("Authentication error, unable to proceed.")
} else {
  
  # Convert the hexadecimal content response to a string
  resp_json <- rawToChar(resp[["content"]])
  
  # Decode the JSON response
  resp_list <- fromJSON(resp_json)
  
  # Extract the data frame values into a stand-alone data frame
  df_data_raw <- resp_list[["value"]]
  
  # Extract paging cookie data (This is only passed if there is more than 1 page of results.
  # by default an API query is limited to 5000 rows, so any extra rows are on additional 
  # pages that need to be queried.)
  paging_cookie_resp <- resp_list[["@Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.fetchxmlpagingcookie"]]
  
  # Check for a paging cookie
  if(length(paging_cookie_resp) == 0){
    print("No paging cookie returned, only one page of results.")
  } else {
    
    print("Retrieving multiple pages of results.")
    
    # Set the starting page number
    page_number <- 1
    
    # Create a variable to determine when we've found the last page of data
    last_page_found <- FALSE
    
    while(last_page_found == FALSE){
      
      #...........................................................................................
      #.. Retrieve multiple pages of results (only applies to data sets with > 5,000 rows)
      #...........................................................................................
      # Split the paging cookie data into a list
      lst_paging_cookie_resp <- str_split(paging_cookie_resp,"\"")
      
      # Retrieve the double-URL-encoded paging cookie
      encoded_paging_cookie <- lst_paging_cookie_resp[[1]][4]
      
      # The paging cookie is DOUBLE url-encoded, so you first need to decode it TWICE. (What a pain this was to figure out)
      decoded_paging_cookie <- URLdecode(URLdecode(encoded_paging_cookie))
      
      # Split the de-coded paging cookie data into a list (so we can extract the page number)
      lst_decoded_paging_data <- str_split(decoded_paging_cookie,"\"")
      
      # If the paging cookie comes in double-quotes, remove the the quotes at the 
      # beginning and end of the string
      decoded_paging_cookie <- str_remove(decoded_paging_cookie,"^\"")
      decoded_paging_cookie <- str_remove(decoded_paging_cookie,"\"$")
      
      # Replace any special characters with their HTML equivalents 
      decoded_paging_cookie <- str_replace_all(decoded_paging_cookie,"&","&amp;")
      decoded_paging_cookie <- str_replace_all(decoded_paging_cookie,"<","&lt;")
      decoded_paging_cookie <- str_replace_all(decoded_paging_cookie,">","&gt;")
      decoded_paging_cookie <- str_replace_all(decoded_paging_cookie,"\"","&quot;")
      
      # URI encode to the paging cookie (This must be done so the API can receive it)
      URI_encoded_paging_cookie <- encodeURIComponent(decoded_paging_cookie)
      
      # Increment the page number by 1
      page_number = page_number + 1
      
      # Create a URL-encoded fetch-XML header that we can add into the existing the URL-encoded XML that 
      # We originally sent to the API
      xml_header <- "paging-cookie=\"PutPagingCookieHere\" page=\"PutPageNumberHere\" distinct="
      url_encoded_xml_header <- URLencode(xml_header)
      
      # Splice in the URI-encoded paging cookie and page number
      url_encoded_xml_header <- url_encoded_xml_header %>%
        str_replace("PutPagingCookieHere",URI_encoded_paging_cookie) %>%
        str_replace("PutPageNumberHere",as.character(page_number))
      
      # We now have the paging cookie and page number in the appropriate URL and URI encoded formats. 
      # We can now splice this extra information into the XML header of our original API request. 
      new_url_xml <- str_replace(url_xml,"distinct=",url_encoded_xml_header)
      
      # Create a new Web API query URL with the updated XML data
      url_fetch <- paste0(base_url, dynamics_entity, url_add_on, new_url_xml) 
      # url_fetch
      
      # Retrieve the next page of data
      resp <- GET(url = url_fetch
                  , config(token = mytoken)
                  , add_headers(Prefer = "odata.include-annotations=\"*\"") # This header is required to get legible text returned
      )
      
      # Check for an error returned in the response
      if(http_error(resp) == TRUE){
        
        print("Error while retrieving 2nd page of results, unable to proceed.")
        last_page_found <- TRUE
        
      } else {
        
        # Convert the hexadecimal content response to a string
        resp_json <- rawToChar(resp[["content"]])
        
        # Decode the JSON response
        resp_list <- fromJSON(resp_json)
        
        # Extract the data frame values into a stand-alone data frame
        df_data_raw_next_page <- resp_list[["value"]]
        
        # The API only returns columns that hold data. To make sure our columns match, 
        # we need to add any columns missing from either data frame to the other data frame
        # so we can join them.
        
        # Add any columns missing from the original data frame to the new one
        prev_page_names <- names(df_data_raw)  # Vector of columns you want in this data.frame
        missing <- setdiff(prev_page_names, names(df_data_raw_next_page))  # Find names of missing columns
        df_data_raw_next_page[missing] <- NA                    # Add them, filled with NA results
        
        # Add any columns missing from the new data frame to the original one
        next_page_names <- names(df_data_raw_next_page)  # Vector of columns you want in this data.frame
        missing <- setdiff(next_page_names, names(df_data_raw))  # Find names of missing columns
        df_data_raw[missing] <- NA                    # Add them, filled with NA results
        
        # Append these rows onto the original data frame and
        # filter out any extra rows from the join
        df_data_raw <- df_data_raw %>%
          rbind(df_data_raw_next_page, use.names=TRUE) %>%
          filter(`@odata.etag` != "TRUE") %>%
          distinct()
        
        # Extract paging cookie data (This is only passed if there is more than 1 page of results.
        # by default an API query is limited to 5000 rows, so any extra rows are on additional 
        # pages that need to be queried.)
        paging_cookie_resp <- resp_list[["@Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.fetchxmlpagingcookie"]]
        
        # Note if we're on the last page of results so we exit the loop
        if(nrow(df_data_raw_next_page) < 5000){
          last_page_found <- TRUE 
        } else {
          print(paste0("Page ",page_number," retrieved, retrieving page ", page_number + 1))
        }
      }
    }
  }
  
  #...........................................................................................
  #.. Clean the returned column names
  #...........................................................................................
  
  # Keep formatted columns only, removing the non-formatted versions from the data frame.
  # The API gives 2 versions of each formatted column, a formatted version and a non-formatted version with the GUID.
  # We only want the formatted version, since that's readable to the human eye. We don't want a GUID.
  
  # Set the starting index to 1
  i <- 1
  
  # Loop over the columns in the data frame
  while(i <= length(names(df_data_raw))){
    
    # Extract the current column name
    str_col_name <-names(df_data_raw)[i]
    # print(paste0("Cleaning column ",i," - ",str_col_name))
    
    # Proceed if we have a column returned
    if(is.na(str_col_name) == FALSE){
      
      # Check for unwanted meta data columns we can remove
      condition_1 <- grepl("@Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM",str_col_name, ignore.case = TRUE)
      condition_2 <- grepl("Display.V1.AttributeName",str_col_name, ignore.case = TRUE)
      condition_3 <- grepl("@odata_etag",str_col_name, ignore.case = TRUE)
      condition_4 <- grepl("@odata.etag",str_col_name, ignore.case = TRUE)
      
      # Check to see if an unwanted column has been found
      if(condition_1 | condition_2 | condition_3 | condition_4){
        
        # Remove the column
        df_data_raw <- df_data_raw %>%
          select(-all_of(str_col_name))
        
        # Reset the index since a column was removed
        i <- 0
        
      } else {
        
        # Check to see if it's formatted column
        if(grepl("@OData.Community.Display.V1.FormattedValue",str_col_name, ignore.case = TRUE)){
          
          # Extract the base column name by removing the huge suffix "@OData.Community.Display.V1.FormattedValue"
          str_base_col <- str_replace(str_col_name,"@OData.Community.Display.V1.FormattedValue","")
          
          # Remove the base column if it exists (leaving us with only the formatted version of 
          # the column, not the original version of it.)
          df_data_raw <- df_data_raw %>%
            select(-all_of(str_base_col))
          
          # Reset the index since a column was removed
          i <- 0
          
        } else {
          str_base_col <- str_col_name
        }
        
        # Remove any prefixes or suffixes from the column name
        str_new_col <- str_replace(str_base_col,"_","") # Remove "_" prefix
        str_new_col <- str_replace(str_new_col,"^_","") # Remove "_" prefix
        str_new_col <- str_replace(str_new_col,"\\.","_") # Replace any periods with an underscore
        str_new_col <- str_replace(str_new_col,"_value$","") # Remove "_value" suffix
        
        # Re-name the old column name to the new one
        df_data_raw <- df_data_raw %>%
          rename(!!str_new_col := all_of(str_col_name))
        
        # If this is a character column that has the word "date" in it attempt to convert it to the 
        # a date-type column. 
        if(grepl("date",str_new_col,ignore.case = TRUE) & typeof(df_data_raw[,i]) == "character"){
          
          print(paste0("Attempting to convert ",str_new_col," to a date format."))
          # Attempt to assign the proper data type
          df_data_raw <- df_data_raw %>%
            mutate(attempt_mdy = mdy(!!as.symbol(str_new_col))) 
          
          # If we had at least 1 successful conversion, convert the
          # column to the date format
          if(sum(is.na(df_data_raw$attempt_mdy) == FALSE) > 0){
            df_data_raw <- df_data_raw %>%
              mutate(!!as.symbol(str_new_col) := attempt_mdy)
          }
          
          # Drop the attempt_mdy column
          df_data_raw <- df_data_raw %>%
            select(-attempt_mdy)
        }
      }
    }
    # Move up the index to the next column
    i <- i + 1
  }
  
  # Select desired columns
  df_data <- df_data_raw %>%
    select(contract_account_number = account_accountnumber       
           , program_duration = programduration
           , contract_start_date = contractstartdate
           , contract_end_date = contractenddate
           , season_year = seasonyear
           , state_code = statecode
           , status_code = statuscode
           , account
           , account_state_code = account_statecode
           , program
           , name
           , kw_new = newkw
           , kw_renewal = renewalkw
           , kw_nomination = kwnominations
           , account_manager = account_accountmanager
           , contract_approval_date = sales_datecontractapproved
           , enrollment_type = enrollmenttype
           , effective_start_date = effectivestartdate
           , effective_end_date = effectiveenddate
           , owner = ownerid
           , program_type = programtype
           , amendment
           , amendment_id = amendmentsid
    )
  
  # Set numeric data types
  df_data <- df_data %>%
    # Remove commas
    mutate(season_year = gsub(",","",season_year)
           , kw_new = gsub(",","",kw_new)
           , kw_renewal = gsub(",","",kw_renewal)
           , kw_nomination = gsub(",","",kw_nomination)) %>%
    # Convert to numeric values
    mutate(season_year = as.numeric(season_year)
           , kw_new = as.numeric(kw_new)
           , kw_renewal = as.numeric(kw_renewal)
           , kw_nomination = as.numeric(kw_nomination))
  
  # Add a load_date_time column
  df_data$load_date_time <- Sys.time()
  
  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone facing the issue where the access_token is coming but refresh_token is not, make sure to add "offline_access" scope in your api_permissions.

Reference - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/702519/endpoint-url-for-offline-access

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35491860)

Answer (score -5):

Give **ALL** permissions. You'll find multiple drop-downs (like the one you're showing in the screenshot).

Each drop down item will have multiple checkboxes referring to different credentials. Check each and you're okey.

Comment: Permissions need to be chosen to the application's need,