# Sample active-directory-dotnet-webapi-onbehalfof not working

Tags: asp.net-web-api, azure-active-directory, send-on-behalf-of

I am trying to run the active-directory-dotnet-webapi-onbehalfof sample in single tenant mode. I've registered the web app service and the native app client as global admin for the tenant. When I run the sample, as a user in the tenant, I can get a token in the client only after consent pops up (first-time for user), and then call makes it to the service, but there it fails with below. Why is that? Documentation says that when a tenant admin registers the application no further consent is needed? I don't think it is possible to give consent when a remote webapi tries to get OBO token. Something seems buggy... AAD team, please clarify how the OBO feature should be used.

AADSTS65001: The user or administrator has not consented to use the application with ID 'b824502e-fe8a-4770-bd98-8d65a07efcc3'. Send an interactive authorization request for this user and resource.
Trace ID: ad7843d0-be4e-4098-8f7c-43c8e5505cfc
Correlation ID: 140466a4-7250-429f-8843-dbd4f63dc60e
Timestamp: 2016-11-25 21:46:13Z

Answer (score 1):

When you register an application using the Azure Management Portal (manage.windowsazure.com) as a tenant administrator, then yes you should not get consent, as long as subsequent tokens are being retrieved in that same tenant.

Because you are seeing consent for the native client app, and then getting that error message, we must assume that something is not being satisfied which would suppress consent for your app.

To resolve this issue, my recommendation is to simply initiate an interactive authorization request just like the error message implies. You can do this by generating a log-in url for your application, with a specific query string that will force prompt tenant wide consent (prompt=admin_consent).

Here is the skeleton for the URL you need to complete:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/<TenantID>/oauth2/authorize?client_id=<AppID>&response_type=code&redirect_uri=<RedirectURI>&resource=<ResourceURI>&prompt=admin_consent
```

You can do this for all the applications you registered, and you should not run into consent issues (assuming you are indeed signing in as a tenant admin).

I hope this resolves your issue.

Comment: Yes, I know the interactive consent trick - the problem is that the OBO feature doesn't work out of the box, as documented. Hope this is fixed soon.

Comment: I feel as though you are finding issues in the OBO feature, when really this is an issue of consent. As i mentioned in my post, the Azure Portal does write consent, assuming a set of requirements are met. The investigation on your side should be to try to understand what issue is causing the consent record to not be recorded. For example, you may find that your user account is actually not a Tenant Admin. Also remember, that each application which takes part in the OBO flow needs to have consent recorded.