# OAuth2 Resource Owner Password Grant via API

Tags: c#, .net, azure, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory

I am currently building an API which requires OAuth2, but cannot find a library to use that will handle the single sign on in a native mobile app via RESTful API only. Most I've found only have a web popup, which has been vetoed for this project. B2C, which is currently functioning, is not capable of using ROPG. Is there a way to easily set this up with another library using C#.NET and Azure?

**UPDATE:**

Attempting to use B2C per Fei Xue answer below, we got to the point of getting an access token from Microsoft Graph.
In the body of the POST, we did the following:

> resource=https%3A%2F%2FGraph.windows.net&client_id=[B2C Settings -
>   Applications -
>   AppId]&grant_type=password&username=rob%40[tenant].onmicrosoft.com&password=[password]&client_secret=[B2C Settings - Applications - App Key - client_secret]

Our error with the namespace was due to the usernames we were trying. This is a B2C tenant using email as the username and that was the reason for the namespace error. The only way we got past that error was to create a B2C user with the email address ending in the tenant, like so:

> rob@[tenant].onmicrosoft.com

We are getting an access token now, but that token does not authenticate with our azure app service api app, which was the original goal.

What we are trying to accomplish is to send the username and password that is valid for a B2C signin and get an IdToken or Access Token that is valid for the api app. The api app connects to B2C via App Service Authentication settings configured for AAD with the Client ID and secret setup from the B2C Settings Application.

**UPDATE:**

Attempting to pass through the graph.windows.net token for authentication in our Azure web api, we added in the https://Graph.windows.net allowed token audience in our App Service – Authentication – Active Directory Authentication configuration.

However, passing the graph access token in the Bearer header to the API still results in

> “Authorization has been denied for this request”.

Found out that if we make the Issuer Url blank like in the example below, it now accepts the Graph token!

However, this causes issues when trying to hit

> https://[our_web_app].azurewebsites.net/.auth/login/aad

It goes to the common Microsoft login now. Previously it directed to our B2C sign up in policy because the Issuer Url was set to:

> https://login.microsoftonline.com/[tenantname].onmicrosoft.com/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration?p=[B2C_SignUpIn_Policy]

In fact, if we also pull up the policy from within our app (which was working before removing the Issuer Url) to the sign in policy, we can sign in, but that returned Access Token now always comes back as Unauthorized in the web API calls.

*Should the Issuer Url be left blank?*

Also, since making the Issuer Url blank, the server takes much longer to respond to API calls when we send a request using a Graph access token in the Header Authorization Bearer. It went from taking about 1-2 seconds (using a valid B2C access token obtained from MSAL or the web login above) to taking about 10-15 seconds to respond that it is an authenticated request. That kind of speed is a show stopper for us. *Does validating a graph call in this manner normally take this long?*

Answer (score 5):

The feature is now available in preview and works pretty well:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/configure-ropc

Important note: **The POST url mentioned in the documentation is wrong.**

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/{{Aad_Tenant}}/b2c_1_ropc_auth/oauth2/v2.0/
```

Must be:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/{{Aad_Tenant}}/oauth2/v2.0/token?p=b2c_1_ropc_auth
```

The calling application must have native client enabled, otherwise you will get this error:

> AADB2C90224: Resource owner flow has not been enabled for the application.

Answer (score 2):

Update to the answer from @AlexAIT.

The URL in the documentation now works for AD B2C.

```
https://<tenant-name>.b2clogin.com/<tenant-name>.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1A_ROPC_Auth/oauth2/v2.0/token
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/add-ropc-policy?tabs=app-reg-ga&pivots=b2c-user-flow#test-the-ropc-flow

If you get the error:

> AADB2C90224: Resource owner flow has not been enabled for the
> application

Navigate to application -> Authentication and select `Enable the following mobile and desktop flows:`.

[image]

Wait a few minutes and then it will start to work.

Github thread:

https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/50330

Answer (score 1):

The Azure AD B2C has already support the Resource Owner Password Grant flow, you can send the HTTP request like below to using this flow:

```
POST: https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/token
resource=https%3A%2F%2FGraph.windows.net&client_id={client_id}&grant_type=password&username={userName}&password={password}&client_secret={secret}
```

**Note:** this flow only work for the local accounts as social identity providers(Facebook, Google, etc) don't support this.

### Update

The token above is acquiring the token for `https://graph.windows.net`. To pass through the authentication of web API which protect by Azure AD, we need to specify this as the **ALLOWED TOKEN AUDIENCES** like figure below:
[image]

Comment: I'm getting a 404 when trying that after filling in the tenant and client ID as well as UN/PW/client_secret. Are you sure this works for B2C and not just Azure AD?

Comment: Yes, I tested both the application register directly the under Azure B2C tenant and under  Azure B2C tenant's [B2C features blade](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-app-registration). Would you mind share the detailed request? Please don't contain the password in the request.

Comment: Is there a supported way to complete user registration with the same flow? I cannot find any Microsoft documentation on this at all.

Comment: Yes, you need to grant the permission of the app `Read and write directory data` delegated permission for the **Windows Azure Active Directory**. Then you can use this flow to get the access_token for the windows Azure AD Graph and create the users. More detailed about creating users for Azure AD B2C, you can refer [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-devquickstarts-graph-dotnet).

Comment: So I followed those and got a command line app working that will allow us to create users, update user password, etc. Can probably somehow work that into our API.

However, the greater issue is the ROPG for getting the token for existing users, otherwise, we still do not get a valid token and would still have to pop the B2C window.

Comment: Anyway, in going through all of it, when I use the following call, I still get errors for obtaining the token:
https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/v2.0/token?resource=https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.net%2F&client_id=cid&grant_type=password&username=un&password=pw&client_secret=secret

Comment: If we run that, we get the following error:
{
  "error": "invalid_request",
  "error_description": "AADSTS90100: The 'resource' request parameter is not supported.\r\nTrace ID: 837e903b-c785-4139-9bfa-b2762ea91e00\r\nCorrelation ID: bc933051-7e8b-4429-b54e-bc7f681d1487\r\nTimestamp: 2017-06-27 16:57:11Z",
  "error_codes": [
    90100
  ],
  "timestamp": "2017-06-27 16:57:11Z",
  "trace_id": "837e903b-c785-4139-9bfa-b2762ea91e00",
  "correlation_id": "bc933051-7e8b-4429-b54e-bc7f681d1487"
}

Comment: If we run it without the /v2.0/, then we get the following error:
{
  "error": "invalid_request",
  "error_description": "AADSTS90002: The requested namespace does not exist.\r\nTrace ID: 02586728-56e4-4247-b054-59be39952a00\r\nCorrelation ID: 5a2cfd00-8017-44ea-b4ec-b43f7b677a41\r\nTimestamp: 2017-06-27 17:01:11Z",
  "error_codes": [
    90002
  ],
  "timestamp": "2017-06-27 17:01:11Z",
  "trace_id": "02586728-56e4-4247-b054-59be39952a00",
  "correlation_id": "5a2cfd00-8017-44ea-b4ec-b43f7b677a41"
}

Comment: If we take out the “resource” request parameter then we get the following error:
{
  "error": "invalid_grant",
  "error_description": "AADSTS70000: The grant is not supported by this API version\r\nTrace ID: aeb1ee9a-74d2-49f9-90be-cb8ce4802300\r\nCorrelation ID: 0358bf8f-20b0-4802-97b2-37034bd3033c\r\nTimestamp: 2017-06-27 17:02:02Z",
  "error_codes": [
    70000
  ],
  "timestamp": "2017-06-27 17:02:02Z",
  "trace_id": "aeb1ee9a-74d2-49f9-90be-cb8ce4802300",
  "correlation_id": "0358bf8f-20b0-4802-97b2-37034bd3033c"
}

Comment: The app register on Azure portal doesn't support v2.0 endpoint. And for the `AADSTS90002` error, please ensure the tenant is correct.

Comment: I'm now getting this after fixing the username:

"error": "invalid_resource",
  "error_description": "AADSTS50001: The application named https://graph.microsoft.net was not found in the tenant named tenantname.onmicrosoft.com.  This can happen if the application has not been installed by the administrator of the tenant or consented to by any user in the tenant.  You might have sent your authentication request to the wrong tenant.

Comment: \r\nTrace ID: 788baf52-0512-477c-bb6d-a51416f43000\r\nCorrelation ID: 6c7e37f3-7e31-4c64-853a-46c8d0cc3174\r\nTimestamp: 2017-06-28 13:56:11Z",
  "error_codes": [
    50001
  ],
  "timestamp": "2017-06-28 13:56:11Z",
  "trace_id": "788baf52-0512-477c-bb6d-a51416f43000",
  "correlation_id": "6c7e37f3-7e31-4c64-853a-46c8d0cc3174"

Comment: @Rob For the authentication issue please refer the post of GouldComputing.

Comment: I've updated the original question to address the current state.

Comment: @Rob There are two kinds of application we can create in the Azure AD B2C application. First is the normal application as we register in a normal Azure AD. And it does support the resource owner password credentials flow. The other is Azure B2C app which support to login using the policy to enable the consumer identity data provider. It is not able to mixing these two apps(eg. protect the app service using the Azure B2C app and send the token acquire using the resource owner password credentials) .

Comment: The Azure AD B2C app actually using the Azure AD V2.0 endpoint for the authentication/authorization.(refer [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-access-tokens#requesting-a-token)). If you want the Azure AD B2C app also support the resource owner password credentials flow, I suggest that you submit the feedback from [here](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/category/160596-b2c).

Comment: In-addition, for the performance issue, I suggest that you test it with simple code in the web API since I am not able to reproduce this issue. The API works as quick as as I config the issue URL.

Comment: It is important to note that while this works, it is not an officially supported mechanism.

Comment: Can I use this to get around the server-to-server constraint in the current ROPC flow outlined here? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/add-ropc-policy?tabs=app-reg-ga&pivots=b2c-custom-policy#ropc-flow-notes

Answer (score 0):

I work with Rob, and we did finally get the call to work with 
https://login.microsoftonline.com/[tenant_ending_in_onmicrosoft.com]/oauth2/token

In the body of the POST, we did the following:

> resource=https%3A%2F%2FGraph.windows.net&client_id=[B2C Settings - Applications - AppId]&grant_type=password&username=rob%40[tenant].onmicrosoft.com&password=[password]&client_secret=[B2C Settings - Applications - App Key - client_secret]

Our error with the namespace was due to the usernames we were trying. This is a B2C tenant using email as the username and that was the reason for the namespace error. The only way we got past that error was to create a B2C user with the email address ending in the tenant, like so:

> rob@[tenant].onmicrosoft.com.

We are getting an access token now, but that token does not authenticate with our azure app service api app, which was the original goal. What we are trying to accomplish is to send the username and password that is valid for a B2C signin and get an IdToken or Access Token that is valid for the api app. The api app connects to B2C via App Service Authentication settings configured for AAD with the Client ID and secret setup from the B2C Settings Application.

**UPDATE:**
If I add ?p=[B2C SignUpIn Policy] to the POST, then we get the following error:

> AADB2C90224: Resource owner flow has not been enabled for the
>   application.

Comment: The issue is different with the orignal post, I suggest that modify the orignal the post so that other community can understand the thread more easily. And to fix the new issue please see the update of my post.

Comment: The calling application must have native client enabled, otherwise you will get the error you mention in your update.