# Can I use "Resource Owner Password Grant" flow with Azure AD B2C

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

I need to be able to get an identity/access token to a backend API for a native client, where the native client must use native UI to collect username and password.

I want to use Azure AD B2C but I cannot get clear, explicit info if the Resource Owner Password Grant flow is supported. Is it possible to get a token from Azure AD B2C by programmatically posting username and password somewhere?

Comment: I was just announced that this is close to being in private preview, so it is moving forward :) See https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/suggestions/13817784-add-support-for-resource-owner-password-credential

Comment: Thanks, also received the info. We had to dump b2c in the end for both complexity and cost.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Azure AD B2C does not support the "Resource Owner" password grant yet.**

You can support this feature ask and get updates on its progress by voting for it in the Azure AD B2C feedback forum: [Add support for Resource Owner Password Credentials flow in Azure AD B2C](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/suggestions/13817784-add-support-for-resource-owner-password-credential).

Comment: Thanks for the swift response, please can you reconcile this with the advice given by a MSFT employee here https://stackoverflow.com/a/44539932/442396  Is this approach technically feasible as a short term solution?

Comment: That approach in that answer does work, though it's a workaround and not officially supported. It also has several caveats and complexities. If it works for you, it's a "use it at your own risk".

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to get a token from Azure AD B2C by programmatically posting username and password somewhere?

You can use the [Azure AD Client Credential Flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-protocols-oauth-client-creds) to obtain a token.  See [this SO Post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49036907/185123).

---

ROPC might be the right OAuth Flow for you, but before you start using it, you might want to check out this blog post:
[Why the Resource Owner Password Credentials Grant Type is not Authentication nor Suitable for Modern Applications](https://www.scottbrady91.com/OAuth/Why-the-Resource-Owner-Password-Credentials-Grant-Type-is-not-Authentication-nor-Suitable-for-Modern-Applications).

Answer (score 0):

Resource Owner Password Credential flow is [now supported in Azure AD B2C](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/add-ropc-policy?tabs=app-reg-ga&pivots=b2c-custom-policy).

Do note however that confidential client flow, where the application secret is verified, [is not supported](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/add-ropc-policy?tabs=app-reg-ga&pivots=b2c-custom-policy#ropc-flow-notes).